# @Convert on @Id field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, converters

I'm trying to

```
@Id
@Column(name = "MY_ID_FIELD")
@Convert(converter = IdConverter.class)
private Long id;
```

IdConverter is:

```
@Converter
public class IdConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long, BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToDatabaseColumn(Long attribute) {
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(BigDecimal dbData) {
        return dbData.longValue();
    }
}
```

The converter will map BigDecimal, the attribute field type Hibernate expects given that in the sql server database the id column type is numeric, to Long.

I'm using Spring Data Jpa and my repository is using Long as I would expect to

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> { }
```

Do you have any idea of why it is not working?

Comment: I did not understand your problem. Are you generating any exceptions?

Comment: The JPA spec says something about `@Convert` not being applied to `@Id` fields. I know that DataNucleus JPA allows it, but have also heard of others that don't.

Comment: @Ulisses, my problem is that the application does not start because of the data type of my id field, Long, Hibernate is expecting BigDecimal, as if there were no converter at all. And thanks Billy I'll take a look at the docs then.

Comment: The @BillyFrost is correct, according to the documentation: The Convert annotation should not be used to specify conversion of the following: Id attributes, version attributes, relationship attributes, and attributes explicitly denoted as Enumerated or Temporal. Applications that specify such conversions will not be portable.

Comment: I understand you're trying to map an existing database. Since `NUMERIC` is a floating-type number, I don't think there is much you could do (other than maybe changing the DB to use `BIGINT` instead). If you're creating the database from scratch, then you are most likely trying to use the wrong `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` for your DB

Comment: Yes, that's the situation I'm now, mapping the domain model from an existing database. So, if I convert the data type of my entities ID I'll end up with a hard to migrate application... 
Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 23):

`@Id` and `@Convert` could not be used together. Using `@IdClass` can fix this problem. You just need to move `@Convert` to the `@IdClass`.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PK.class)
public class YourClass {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  ...
}


public class PK implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "MY_ID_FIELD")
  @Convert(converter = IdConverter.class)
  private Long id;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  Even using the @IdClass does not make it work (I tried it).

Comment: It is really work. May be you lost something. I make a simple unit test to prove it. You can check it by the unit test class [IdWithConverterTest.java](https://github.com/rj-hwang/beginner/blob/java-jpa/src/test/java/com/beginner/jpa/idwithconverter/IdWithConverterTest.java). You can also check it through the console log. To run this unit test, 1) `$ git clone --branch java-jpa https://github.com/rj-hwang/beginner.git java-jpa`.2) `$ cd java-jpa`. 3) `$ mvn test -D test=com.beginner.jpa.idwithconverter.IdWithConverterTest`

Comment: I confirm it works. I just tried on an Enum @Id member.

Comment: If using `@Column` on the entity class, it's will be does't work, because cannot using `@Id` with `@Convert` together, we must move the `@Column` from entity class into id class and stay `@Id` on entity class alone.

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone else runs into the same problem I did, you *have* to have the `@Column` annotation on the `@IdClass` in addition to `@Converter` for it to work (instead of relying on the naming strategy).

```java
// doesn't work
public class PK implements Serializable {
  @Convert(converter = IdConverter.class)
  private Long id;
}
```

```java
// works
public class PK implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @Convert(converter = IdConverter.class)
  private Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With EclipseLink 2.7.6 I've got the same problem.
My solution is:

Entity class:

```
    @Entity(name = "xxx")
    public class xxx implements Serializable {
      @EmbeddedId
      private XxxPk pk;
      ...
    }
```

ID class:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class XxxPk implements Serializable {
      @Column(name = "A_TYPE")
      @Convert(converter = ATypeAttributeConverter.class)
      private AType aTypeAttribute;
      ...
    }
```

Converter:

```
    import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
    import javax.persistence.Converter;
        
    @Converter
    public class ATypeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<AType , String> {
        
      @Override
      public String convertToDatabaseColumn(AType agrType) { ... }
        
      @Override
      public AType convertToEntityAttribute(String code) { ... }
    }
```

Enumeration:

```
    public enum AType {
      E1, E2, ...;
      ...
    }
```

I've checked it also with EclipseLink-Converter (org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Converter), but without success.