# @javax.persistance.Convert on @javax.persistance.Id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, type-conversion

I am trying to convert `MongoDb` Object Id to String and use this as a primary key for `MYSQL` Table.
The conversion is happening. `@Convert` converts the ObjectId to String and stores it in MYSQL database. But `@Convert` and `@ID` do not work together. Is there any work around on this? Can `@Convert`and `@ID` be used together?

Here is the code

```
@Converter
public class ObjectIdConvertor implements AttributeConverter<ObjectId,String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ObjectId objectId) {
    if(objectId!=null){
        return objectId.toHexString();
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public ObjectId convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
    return new ObjectId(s);
     }
}


  @Entity
  public class Abc{
  @javax.persistence.Convert(converter = ObjectIdConvertor.class)
  @javax.persistence.Id
  private ObjectId environmentId;

  private String name;

  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Convert on @Id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069361/convert-on-id-field)

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to elaborate?

Comment: Convert is used for converting ObjectId to String and Id for setting as primary key. Both of these are needed. What do you think is the reason for duplication ? Also what can be done instead?

Comment: There is an answer to that on the duplicate question.

Comment: The answer doesn't work.

Comment: Then talk to the person that gave the answer or make in your question clear that you tried what he advised and what the result was.